# Autoplay not working in React.js audio elements: Need help troubleshooting the issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, tsx

i got this error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed

this code

```
 useEffect(() => {

            // Play audio when cardsDataFood is updated
            const audio: any = new Audio("/'file name'/effect.mp3");
            //audio.muted = true;
            audio.play();
    }, [cardsDataFood]);
```

give me this error
i got this error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed

i use React.js , ionic

Comment: [Did you mean `/${file name}/effect.mp3`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using back ticks?

Comment: No, I was just using it as an example, I was just trying to play the sound after each specific event, and thank you for your concern